# How to access my dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

**my dictionary looks like:**

```
account is: {'Discover': ['username', 'dddddd']}
```

I've tried:

```
print(account[0])
```

but it doesn't work.

Im trying to achieve printing out:

```
Discover
```

If someone could help me out? Its been a little while.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Discover` is a key of your dictionary. You can access the keys collection in your dictionary using [keys()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=dictionary#dict.keys) method. Then use each key to access the associated element.

```
for key in account.keys():
    print(key)
    print(account[key])
```

Comment: You don't need to call .keys, if you wanted key and value you could also use .items

Answer (score 3):

Since `Discover` is the only key you could do `print account.keys()[0]`.

**But** if you ever had more keys this won't work every time since dictionaries are arbitrarily ordered (in other words, have no sense of order), you will need to iterate over the `keys()` list, or simply `print account.keys()` to print the whole keys list.

Comment: This is throwing: TypeError: 'dict_keys' object does not support indexing

Comment: @user700070That's because you are using Python 3 (you didn't mention it in your question). In Python 3 you need to convert keys() to a list: `print (list(account.keys())[0])`

Answer (score 0):

if you have more keys, you can loop like this:

```
for i in account:
    print i
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to see the keys of your dict (which in this example is just a single key, `'Discover'`).  Given a dict key, you can use that key to index into the dict to get the associated value.  Here are some examples using the values you gave:

```
>>> account = {'Discover': ['username', 'dddddd']}
>>> account
{'Discover': ['username', 'dddddd']}
>>> account.keys()
['Discover']
>>> account['Discover']
['username', 'dddddd']
>>>
```